# Apache 2.2/Redhat 2.6 with mod_wsgi

Tags: mod-wsgi, redhat, python-3.6, apache2.2

I'm having trouble configuring mod_wsgi with my current set up.

**Redhat 2.6.32**

**Installations setup as non-root user:**

- Apache 2.2 (attempted to get 2.4, but without access to yum the
  dependencies were too much)
- Python 3.6

I seem to have successfully installed mod_wsgi into /apache/modules.

**Problems:**

- The apache directory structure is not what most tutorials indicate, its
  DocumentRoot is in /apache/htdocs, not /var/www/ or /sites-enabled/ or /sites/available/
- I tried putting:`LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` in httpd.conf but I am returned:
  `$HOME/apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Can anyone explain how I can use mod_wsgi with my current setup?

Comment: Try finding that file on your system with `locate libpython3.6m.so.1.0` it may be in the wrong directory (or not even exist?) If it exists and is in the right directory, ensure that the permissions are correct on it (755). Also, how did you install mod_wsgi? Did you compile it yourself, if so, check your python version is definitely 3.6 with `python -v`, if it's not, you've compiled it with the wrong version.

Comment: @MichaelCurry It looks like it exists in the right location (`$HOME/python3/lib). I installed mod_wsgi with a ./configure option `--with-python=$HOME/python3`. This local installation of python 3.6 exists alongside another installation of 2.6.6 so python -v says 2.6.6.

Comment: The directory it's in may not be in apache's library path. You can symlink it to one of the lib directories in apache's library path, or you can add the directory where your libpython2.5.so resides to apache's library path.

Check this question out for help with apache paths: https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable

Comment: @MichaelCurry Thanks, the symlink worked for loading the module! Sorry for the basic question, but should I put my app.wsgi file into my htdocs directory (my DocumentRoot)? I'm trying to build a basic (@'/hello') route that returns "hello word" but my WSGI is evidently not working as it is attempting to access a /hello directory within my apache structure. I'm trying to use bottle.py by the way.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell from this page: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#apache-mod-wsgi although it's been a while since I touched mod_wsgi and I did it with Django, not bottle.py, so I can't give the greatest answer here, sorry :/ I'll add an answer with the symlink :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `libpython3.6m.so.1.0` is not in any of apache's library paths.

You can symlink it to one of the lib directories in apache's library path, or you can add the directory where your libpython3.6m.so.1.0 resides to apache's library path.

Check this question out for help with apache paths: https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely because you self compiled mod_wsgi and the Python installation you used is in a non standard location. In this case you need to se `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable when running `make` for mod_wsgi, with it set to the directory the Python library is in. This way knowledge of where the Python library is is embedded in mod_wsgi. This issue is described in the mod_wsgi documentation:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#unable-to-find-python-shared-library

If you can't rebuild mod_wsgi for some reason, you can also force load the Python shared library into Apache by using:

```
LoadFile /some/path/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

This should be place just before the `LoadModule` line for mod_wsgi.